# Cordova and overlay notifications

Tags: cordova

is it possible to create a notification in the overlay with Cordova? (something like a notification that facebook or some other application creates).
I have searched the web, but haven't found anything other then the notification.alert which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for as a plugin on github.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

This plugin allows you to send notifications to overlay.. Like when you receive new SMS, message on WhatsApp etc.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are looking for toasts? 
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Sorry, I am not looking for toasts.